# Access VBA To Send Query Results to Outlook Email in Table Format

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I would like to send an e-mail with outlook based on the query results from my table but with table formatting (in the body). For some reason the code is only outputting the last record in the table to the e-mail body, instead of looping and adding all 3 records.

Any suggestions, or a better way to code this?

```
Public Sub NewEmail()
'On Error GoTo Errorhandler

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olItem As Variant
    Dim olatt As String
    Dim olMailTem As Variant
    Dim strSendTo As String
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim strTo As String
    Dim strcc As String
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qry As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim strtable As String
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strqry As String

    strqry = "SELECT * From Email_Query"

    strSendTo = "test@email.com"
    strTo = ""
    strcc = ""

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(olMailTem)

    olItem.Display
    olItem.To = strTo
    olItem.CC = strcc
    olItem.Body = ""
    olItem.Subject = "Test E-mail"

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strqry)
    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
       rec.MoveLast
        rec.MoveFirst
        intCount = rec.RecordCount
            For intLoop = 1 To intCount
                olItem.HTMLBody = "<HTML><body>" & _
                "<table border='2'>" & _
                "<tr>" & _
                "<th> Request Type </th>" & _
                "<th> ID </th>" & _
                 "<th> Title </th>" & _
                  "<th> Requestor Name </th>" & _
                   "<th> Intended Audience </th>" & _
                   "<th> Date of Request</th>" & _
                   "<th> Date Needed </th>" & _
                   "</tr>" & _
                   "<tr>" & _
                      "<td>" & rec("Test1") & "</td>" & _
                      "<td>" & rec("Test2") & "</td>" & _
                      "<td>" & rec("Test3") & "</td>" & _
                      "<td>" & rec("Test4") & "</td>" & _
                      "<td>" & rec("Test5") & "</td>" & _
                      "<td>" & rec("Test6") & "</td>" & _
                      "<td>" & rec("Test7") & "</td>" & _
                      "</tr>" & _
                     "<body><HTML>"
                rec.MoveNext
            Next intLoop
    End If

    MsgBox "E-mail Sent"
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing

Exit_Command21_Click:
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , Err.Number
    Resume Exit_Command21_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're changing the HTMLBody every loop rather than adding to it. You should set your header row above the loop, then set each row inside the loop. I like to fill up arrays and use the Join function - it's more visually pleasing to me.

```
Public Sub NewEmail()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olItem As Variant
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strQry As String
    Dim aHead(1 To 7) As String
    Dim aRow(1 To 7) As String
    Dim aBody() As String
    Dim lCnt As Long

    'Create the header row
    aHead(1) = "Request Type"
    aHead(2) = "ID"
    aHead(3) = "Title"
    aHead(4) = "Requestor Name"
    aHead(5) = "Intended Audience"
    aHead(6) = "Date of Request"
    aHead(7) = "Date Needed"

    lCnt = 1
    ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
    aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

    'Create each body row
    strQry = "SELECT * From Email_Query"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

    If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
        Do While Not rec.EOF
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
            aRow(1) = rec("Test1")
            aRow(2) = rec("Test2")
            aRow(3) = rec("Test3")
            aRow(4) = rec("Test4")
            aRow(5) = rec("Test5")
            aRow(6) = rec("Test6")
            aRow(7) = rec("Test7")
            aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
            rec.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

    'create the email
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    olItem.display
    olItem.To = "example@example.com"
    olItem.Subject = "Test E-mail"
    olItem.htmlbody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
    olItem.display

End Sub
```