# Write multi-line email by looping query and format into columns in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, formatting, html-email

I have an access query which I aim to loop through and write the contents to the email body of an outlook email. The below code does the job, however if there are a  lot of lines, it doesn't look great and becomes very busy, visually.

I'd like to either, add some formatting rules which will align each variable into a "column", or make each variable a fixed length so that the pipes ("|") align (and of course making the variable fixed length would probably mean filling some with " " spaces from the left.

Alternatively, I could try sort this issue out using HTML or something? though I have no experience with that, but if this is the way to go, any advise would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Sub Test()

On Error GoTo Error_Handler

Dim strbody, DateStamp
strbody = ""
DateStamp = Format(Date, "Medium Date")

Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
Dim Tem As DAO.Recordset
Set MyDB = CurrentDb()
Set Tem = MyDB.OpenRecordset("TestQuery", dbOpenForwardOnly)
With Tem
    Do While Not .EOF
        strbody = strbody + (CStr(![Num]) + " | " + CStr(Format(![TDate], "Medium Date")) + " | " + CStr(Format(![VDate], "Medium Date")) + " | " + CStr(Format(![QTY], "Standard")) + " | " + ![Name] & vbNewLine)
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
Tem.Close
Set Tem = Nothing

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objEmail As Outlook.MailItem

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .To = "test@abc.com"
    .subject = "Test" & " " & DateStamp
    .Body = strbody
    .Display
End With

Exit_Here:
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
    MsgBox Err & ": " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Here

End Sub
```

Currently, the output in the email looks a bit like this:

```
1234 | 22-Aug-18 | 23-Aug-18 | 1,000.00 | testname 123 
5678 | 21-Aug-18 | 22-Aug-18 | 50,000.00 | second testname of different length
```

The more lines the messier it gets, in addition to missing column names.

Again, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do this with HTML mails.

I have a HTML mail template saved as .oft file, and create the mail item like this:

```
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Set oItem = oOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplatePath)
```

The mail template contains variables like `$TableGoesHere$` which are replaced by the variable data when creating the mail, e.g.

```
Set Tem = MyDB.OpenRecordset("TestQuery", dbOpenForwardOnly)
strTbl = OutlookHtmlTableFromRS(Tem)

oItem.HtmlBody = Replace(oItem.HtmlBody, "$TableGoesHere$", strTbl)
```

with the function:

```
' Create HTML table from a recordset, with all columns except those in <sExcl>
' Returns HTML string to insert into HTML mail
Public Function OutlookHtmlTableFromRS(RS As Recordset, Optional sExcl As String = "") As String

    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim S As String

    ' Table heading row
    S = "<table cellpadding='5' style='text-align:left; border: 1px solid gray; border-collapse:collapse; font-family:Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11pt;'>" & _
        "<tr style='padding:5px;border: 1px solid gray;'>"

    For Each fld In RS.Fields
        If InStr(sExcl, fld.Name) = 0 Then
            S = S & "<th style='border: 1px solid gray;'>" & fld.Name & "</th>"
        End If
    Next fld
    S = S & "</tr>"

    ' Data rows
    Do While Not RS.EOF
        S = S & "<tr style='padding:5px;'>"

        For Each fld In RS.Fields
            If InStr(sExcl, fld.Name) = 0 Then
                S = S & "<td style='border: 1px solid gray;'>" & fld.Value & "</td>"
            End If
        Next fld

        S = S & "</tr>"
        RS.MoveNext
    Loop

    S = S & "</table>"

    RS.Close

    OutlookHtmlTableFromRS = S

End Function
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have a link to a good template? This is a great method but i'm not sure where to begin with creating the HTML file. I found this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30742862/8843765) very useful as it does what i'd like it to but is probably not as flexible as what you're suggesting.

Comment: You simply compose the HTML mail in Outlook as you would do with any other mail. Enter the variables as normal text, either inline for single words or values, or between empty paragraphs for the table. Then File - Save as - oft. @go995

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HTML is the best way! :) With HTML you can create tables in Outlook and have formatting too! And HTML is pretty easy. For any formatting you want, just google it. For example, if you wanted some of the data to be right aligned, you might google "html table right align". There are many helpful websites out there for HTML.

The below VBA code is what I used to put the contents of an Access query into the body of an Outlook email.

While it may look long, it works and it's the best way to copy a query or table into an email.

I love this! My email looks really good!

```
Private Sub btnEmail_Click()
'This will open an email in your Outlook and compose it for you. You review and click send.
'This macro requires the reference "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library" to be enabled.

Dim f As Long, c As Long  
Dim sTable As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olRecip As Recipient
Dim Recipients As Recipients
Dim qField(1 To 4)  'array


''Table Header
qField(1) = "Group Number"
qField(2) = "Group Name"
qField(3) = "PTD"
qField(4) = "Term Date"
sTable = "<table border=0 cellspacing=0 style='padding:0in 5.5pt 0in 5.5pt'><tbody>"
sTable = sTable & "<tr bgcolor=""#70ad47""><font color=""white""><b><td>Group#</td>"  'white font, bold, green fill
sTable = sTable & "<td>Group Name</td>"
sTable = sTable & "<td>PTD</td>"
sTable = sTable & "<td>Term Date</td></b></font></tr>"

''Rows
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TestQuery")
Do Until rs.EOF
    c = c + 1   'counter for the every other row light green
    If c Mod 2 = 0 Then   'every other row light green
        sTable = sTable & "<tr style=""background: #e2efd9"">"
    Else
        sTable = sTable & "<tr>"   'open row
    End If

    For f = 1 To 4        'cells
        sTable = sTable & "<td>" & rs.Fields(qField(f)) & "</td>"
    Next
    sTable = sTable & "</tr>"   'close row
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
sTable = sTable & "</tbody></table>"   'close table
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

''Compose Email
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
olMsg.To = "test@abc.com"
For Each olRecip In olMsg.Recipients
  olRecip.Resolve
Next
olMsg.Subject = "Test " & Format(Date, "Medium Date")
olMsg.Display   'This must go before the .HTMLBody line b/c that is the only way to capture the existing default signature.
olMsg.HTMLBody = "<Body><div>Hello,<br>" & _
  "Please see report below.<br><br>" & sTable & olMsg.HTMLBody
```