# Send an outlook email to each record in the table in a table format

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook

I have a MS Access table and  want to send an email to each record in the table in a table format. For row in the table bearing same city or Country, I expect the  outlook email to have those records in one table.

I have included a dummy table [DummyTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOX81.png) whose records I would retrieve using an SQL query: SELECT * FROM DummyTable
I have created the table in vba using this solution I found here [access-vba-to-send-query-results-to-outlook-email-in-table-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741735/access-vba-to-send-query-results-to-outlook-email-in-table-format)

```
Public Sub NewEmail()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olItem As Variant
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim strQry As String
Dim aHead(1 To 7) As String
Dim aRow(1 To 7) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long

'Create the header row
aHead(1) = "Request Type"
aHead(2) = "ID"
aHead(3) = "Title"
aHead(4) = "Requestor Name"
aHead(5) = "Intended Audience"
aHead(6) = "Date of Request"
aHead(7) = "Date Needed"

lCnt = 1
ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"

'Create each body row
strQry = "SELECT * From Email_Query"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQry)

If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
    Do While Not rec.EOF
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
        aRow(1) = rec("Test1")
        aRow(2) = rec("Test2")
        aRow(3) = rec("Test3")
        aRow(4) = rec("Test4")
        aRow(5) = rec("Test5")
        aRow(6) = rec("Test6")
        aRow(7) = rec("Test7")
        aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td> 
</tr>"
        rec.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"

'create the email
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)

olItem.display
olItem.To = "example@example.com"
olItem.Subject = "Test E-mail"
olItem.htmlbody = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)
olItem.display

End Sub
```

My ideal solution would result in this table as the email body if I want to send an email to names in my table whose country are TRNC [Country "TRNC"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etNNh.png) and for county UK a separate  table for the email body as thus [Country "UK"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwBE0.png).

My approach would be to create an array to hold the records from the DummyTable and then loop through each record and create a table for records with same country names, but my implementation fails me and I've been on this for 2 weeks.

Comment: Data in table image doesn't even match up with field names referenced in code. Doesn't look like you've done much to tailor code example to your db. Data should be provided as text table not image.

Comment: So you want to send the same records to Adam and Mina? Same records to Graeme and Briann? Okay if they see each others email or should this be BCC addressing?

Comment: Exactly! Same records should be send to Adam and Mina. Also same records to Graeme and Briann

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given sample data, consider:

```
Public Sub NewEmail()

Dim olApp As Object
Dim olItem As Variant
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim aRow(1 To 5) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim strCountry As String
Dim strHTML As String
Dim strEmail As String
Dim x As Integer

strHTML = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "Name</th><th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "Country</th><th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "City</th><th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "School</th><th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "Email</th>"
strHTML = strHTML & "XXX</table></body></html>"

lCnt = 1

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")

Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM DummyTable ORDER BY Country, City, School, Name")

If Not (rec.BOF And rec.EOF) Then
    strCountry = rec!Country
    For x = 1 To rec.recordCount
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
        aRow(1) = rec("Name") & "</td><td>"
        aRow(2) = rec("Country") & "</td><td>"
        aRow(3) = rec("City") & "</td><td>"
        aRow(4) = rec("School") & "</td><td>"
        aRow(5) = rec("Email") & "</td>"
        aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "") & "</tr>"
        strEmail = strEmail & rec!Email & ";"
        If x < rec.recordCount Then rec.MoveNext
        If x = rec.recordCount Or strCountry <> rec!Country Then
            'create the email
            Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
            olItem.Display
            olItem.To = "my email"
            olItem.BCC = strEmail
            olItem.Subject = "Test E-mail"
            olItem.HTMLBody = Replace(strHTML, "xxx", Join(aBody, vbNewLine))
            olItem.Display
            lCnt = 0
            strEmail = ""
            strCountry = rec!Country
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I implemented the code according to your solution. I encounter the "End if without block if" error. I also tried different debug solutions like building the if statements under the for loop block, all to no avail.

Comment: The first "End If" is the line that gets highlighted in Debug mode

Comment: Code works perfect for me.